# Can't use string ("1") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, perl5.10

In a Perl daemon reacting to various events I'm trying to use [a Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in 2 cases by creating anonymous subroutines, which should just return a value of 1 aka "true" (please scroll to the right to see the **check** subroutines for **LOGIN** and **ALIVE** events):

```
package User;

our %EVENTS = (
        LOGIN   => {handler => \&handleLogin,   check => sub {1},     },
        CHAT    => {handler => \&handleChat,    check => \&mayChat,   },
        JOIN    => {handler => \&handleJoin,    check => \&mayJoin,   },
        LEAVE   => {handler => \&handleLeave,   check => \&mayLeave,  },
        ALIVE   => {handler => sub {},          check => sub {1},     },
        BID     => {handler => \&handleBid,     check => \&checkArgs, },
        TAKE    => {handler => \&handleTake,    check => \&checkArgs, },
  # .... more events ....
);


sub action($$$) {
        my $user  = shift;
        my $event = shift;
        my $arg   = shift;
        my $game  = $user->{GAME};

        unless (exists $EVENTS{$event}) {
                print STDERR "wrong event: $event\n";
                return;
        }

        my $handler = $EVENTS{$event}->{handler};
        my $check   = $EVENTS{$event}->{check};

        return unless $user->$check->($arg); # XXX fails
        $user->$handler->($arg);
}

sub mayChat($$) {
        my $user = shift;

        return if $user->{KIBITZER};
}

# ...... more methods here ...

1;
```

Unfortunately I get the runtime error for **LOGIN** event:

```
Can't use string ("1") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use
```

Does anybody please know how to fix it here?

How to provide a "function pointer" to an anonymous Perl subroutine?

The **handler => \&sub { 1 }** doesn't do it either.

Using perl 5.8.8 and perl 5.10.1 on CentOS 5.x and 6.x

**UPDATE:**

I've also tried following:

```
    my $check = $EVENTS{$event}->{check};
    return unless $check->($user, $arg);
```

but it doesn't help. I think this rules out the "missing blessing" suggested in some answers.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have extended the source code snippet in my original question. **The background is:** I'm in the process of refactoring of my source code and thus I've created the **%EVENTS** hash as listed above, so that for each incoming *event* (a string sent over TCP-socket from [a Flash client](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/)) there is a reference to a subroutine (**check**) which validates the event and a reference to another subroutine (**handler**) which performs some actions. I'm not sure if other subroutines work - I'm stuck already at the first **LOGIN** *event*.

I also don't understand why doesn't **check => sub { 1 }** above work - isn't **sub** supposed to return a reference to an anonymous subroutine  (when the name is omitted - according to [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) section 4)?

**UPDATE 3:**

The output of **print Dumper(\%EVENTS)** -

```
$VAR1 = {
          'PLAY' => {
                      'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                    },
          'JOIN' => {
                      'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                    },
          'OVER1' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'ALIVE' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'DISCARD' => {
                         'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                         'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       },
          'MISS1' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'LOGIN' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'TAKE' => {
                      'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                      'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                    },
          'ONEMORE' => {
                         'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                         'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       },
          'OVER2' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'MISS2' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'EXACT' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'TRUST' => {
                       'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'LEAVE' => {
                       'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                     },
          'DEFEND' => {
                        'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                        'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      },
          'OPEN' => {
                      'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                      'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                    },
          'REVEAL' => {
                        'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                        'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      },
          'CHAT' => {
                      'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                    },
          'DECLARE' => {
                         'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                         'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                       },
          'BACK' => {
                      'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                    },
          'MISERE' => {
                        'check' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                        'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                      },
          'BID' => {
                     'check' => $VAR1->{'PLAY'}{'check'},
                     'handler' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                   }
        };
```

Comment: To which line in your code does the error message refer?

Comment: Hi Jack, I've marked it with an "XXX fails", please scroll to the right

Comment: `$obj->$code->(@args)` is like `my $val = $obj->$code; $val->(@args);' because of the precedence of the `->` operator (see `perldoc perlop`). I think what you're looking for rather is `$obj->$code(@args)` which is like `$code->($obj, @args)`.

Comment: Oh.  Prototypes.  That didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the particular event that is surfacing the problem; the actual bug is in `action`.  In particular, the line

```
    return unless $user->$check->($arg); # XXX fails
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  Between the presence of prototypes and Perl's willingness to try and call a sub specified by name, you wind up eventually calling `User::` for the `CHAT` event.  Which doesn't seem to be what you intended for it to do.

The more correct call looks like

```
    return unless $check->($user, $arg);
```

This expects `$check` to contain a subref (which it does), dereferences it and calls it.  This works even though sometimes `$check` will refer to a prototyped function.

That leaves the problem that this procedural code doesn't respect inheritance.  To do that, you have to rephrase `%EVENTS` a bit.  Thus:

```
our %EVENTS = (
        LOGIN   => {handler => \&handleLogin,   check => sub {1},     },
        CHAT    => {handler => \&handleChat,    check => sub { shift->mayChat(@_) },
        ...
);
```

Note that you are strongly discouraged to mix function prototypes and Perl OO programming precisely because it can lead to hard-to-diagnose problems like this one.

In reference to your other question:  `my $foo = sub { }` is indeed how you construct anonymous subroutines.  But you do need to call them appropriately.

Comment: +1 When `$check` is a code ref to a `User` method, `$check->($user,$arg)` is the same as `$user->name_of_method($arg)`, and when `$check` is more trivial (`$check=sub{1}`), `$check->($user,$arg)` is still valid and meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

`$check` is already a code reference, so you could say

```
return unless $check->($arg);
```

Your existing code could also be salvaged if `$check` were a reference to code that returned a code reference:

```
our %EVENTS = ( LOGIN => { ..., check => sub { sub { 1 } }, } ... );
```

Think of `sub { }` as a "code reference" operator the way that `\` is an operator to create a scalar reference, or `[...]` is an operator to create an array reference.

Comment: But if I call just $check->($arg) then it won't work for the other events - because mayChat(), mayJoin(), mayLeave(), etc. are methods to be called on the $user object.

Comment: You and darch hit on the right answer. You'll want to make that `$check->($user,$arg)`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `$check` is a code reference,

```
$user->$check->($arg);
```

won't work.

As a self-contained example:

```
    > perl -e 'use strict;use warnings;my $a=17;$a->("whatever");'
Can't use string ("17") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at -e line 1.
```

So you'll have to look more carefully at the structure of your data and avoid treating scalars as code references.

Comment: That's a good comment, thank you. Doesn't answer the main question though. By the way $user is a User.pm object, so I think it will work in my case.

Comment: Well, to fix it, you'll need to look more closely at the structure of your data.  [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is your friend.

Comment: $check is not an object, it is a method defined in User.pm. And $user is an User.pm object. And to rephrase my question would probably be: perl -e '%events = (check=>sub {1}); print "ok\n" if $events{check}->()==1;' - here calling the anonymous subroutine seems to work, but in my code not, for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I use Data::Dumper a lot. Why not just provide the answer if you've spotted the error?

Comment: Edit made: to be more specific, `$check` seems to be a scalar, and not a subroutine reference.  Thus, any attempt to call it as a code reference will produce an error.

Comment: Yes, I understood sofar too, thanks. But how to make it a sub ref?

Comment: You'll have to change the structure of your data.  Make it a sub ref instead of a scalar.  Take a look at [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: Answer is simply wrong:  $check is a code reference, its not being a code reference cannot be the problem.

Comment: @darch - With only the partial code given the question, it's far from obvious that `$check` is a code reference.

Answer (score 2):

looks like $event is either LOGIN or ALIVe, both have anonymous subs for the check key that return 1. $check is locally defined to that subroutine, and returns 1, the code then attempts to access the value '1' in the user hash/object as a hash

Answer (score 1):

My own answer - the following seems to work, I probably was dereferencing my sub refs in a wrong way...

```
sub action($$$) {
        my $user  = shift;
        my $event = shift;
        my $arg   = shift;

        my $handler = $EVENTS{$event}->{handler};
        my $check   = $EVENTS{$event}->{check};

        return unless &$check($user, $arg);
        &$handler($user, $arg);
}
```

Comment: Right. `&$check(@args)` is the same thing as `$check->(@args)`, as `perl  -MO=Deparse ...` will verify.

Answer (score 0):

The key fact about your program that you left out of your question is this:  `mayChat` and friends all return subroutine references.  These are then evaluated at

```
    return unless $user->$check->($arg); # XXX falis
```

.  Entries in `%EVENTS` are references to routines that return subroutine references.  Once we've stated it in those terms, the problem with your original code becomes obvious.

`$EVENTS{LOGIN}->{check}` is a reference to a sub that returns an integer, when what is expected is a reference to a sub that returns a reference to a sub.  If we make it a reference to a sub that returns a reference to a sub:

```
    LOGIN   => {phase => undef,      handler => \&handleLogin,   check => sub { sub {1} },     },
```

, it works.

The fix for your problem is to (1) make those entries be subs that return subs and (2) document the interface of `%EVENTS` so you are the last person to have this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't true. I have extended the source code snippet in my original question, so that this more visible. I'm in the process of refactoring of my source code and thus I've created the %EVENTS hash as listed above, so that for each incoming "event" (a string sent over TCP-socket from Flash client) there is a reference to a subroutine (check) which validates the event and a reference to another subroutine (handler) which performs some actions. I'm not sure if other subroutines work - I'm stuck already at the first LOGIN event.

Comment: Wait.  You're saying you don't know that the other calls work?  It's true the above was predicated on the idea that everything you didn't mention as not working worked.  If what you're saying is that `action` has never worked for any input, that's a completely different kettle of fish.

Comment: You keep implying that I have some very special setup or have omitted some important key facts. This isn't so, I have a mere hash of hashes with few subroutine references. I think, I have provided enough information in my question too.

Comment: The above answer was based on unwarranted assumptions, primarily that the code in question worked in some cases.  That made it wrong.  There is in fact one important piece of information omitted from the question:  That the code in question does not work for any case.  If you'd mentioned that, you'd have gotten an answer more quickly.