# Can't use string ("1") as subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, dispatch-table

I know this is a duplicate of [Can't use string ("1") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929754/cant-use-string-1-as-a-subroutine-ref-while-strict-refs-in-use)
but I can't figure out what my problem is with the call to the dispatch table. The code seems to execute, but the following error appears in the log: `Can't use string ("1") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at C:/filepath/file.pl line 15.`

```
#! C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Custom::MyModule;
use CGI ':standard'; 

my $dispatch_table = {
      getLRFiles => \&Custom::MyModule::getLRFiles,
      imageMod => \&Custom::MyModule::imageMod,
      # More functions
  };

my $perl_function = param("perl_function");
($dispatch_table->{$perl_function}->(\@ARGV) || sub {})->(); # Error occurs on this line
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a custom module, and it's probably something stupid, since I'm not extremely familiar with Perl, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
($dispatch_table->{$perl_function}->(\@ARGV) || sub {})->();
```

is same thing as

```
my $x = $dispatch_table->{$perl_function}->(\@ARGV);
($x || sub {})->(); # $x is probably not code ref
```

Try,

```
($dispatch_table->{$perl_function} || sub {})->(\@ARGV);
```

or perhaps

```
$_ and $_->(\@ARGV) for $dispatch_table->{$perl_function};
```

Comment: For your first suggestion to try, I'm now getting `Premature end of script headers.` and `Use of uninitialized value $perl_function in hash element`. That makes a lot of sense though.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now. I wasn't passing in an argument properly. Thanks!